# Grails querying a domain class with a collection not producing expected results

Tags: hibernate, grails

(Grails 2.4.2)

I'm trying to obtain a list of Stories that a user can access.  So all Stories the user is the owner of the story or user is in a collection of Editors of this story.  I've tried many different queries, from createCriteria to writing HQL.  I can query all stories that the user is an owner of.  I can query all stories that the user is in the collection of editors, but when I put the queries together with an OR..I don't get the right results.

```
class Story {
  String title
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  String description
  Boolean isPublic
  List storyContent = []
  User owner

    static belongsTo = [owner: User]
    static hasMany = [storyContent : StoryContent, viewers : Viewer, editors : Editor] 
...more


class Editor  { 
    User user
    static belongsTo = [story: Story]
```

When I do the following query:

```
def hql = "from Story as s left outer join s.editors as se where s.owner.username = 'joe'"
def results = Story.executeQuery(hql)
```

I get the correct results:

```
Result: [[com.storycreate.Story : 3, com.storycreate.Editor : 1], [com.storycreate.Story : 2, null]]
```

Joe is the owner of story 2 and story 3.  Now I query for all stories where Joe is the editor

```
def hql = "from Story as s left outer join s.editors as se where se.user.username='joe'"
def results = Story.executeQuery(hql)
```

and get the correct results: (Joe is both editor and owner of story 3 and editor of story4)

```
Result: [[com.storycreate.Story : 3, com.storycreate.Editor : 1], [com.storycreate.Story : 4, com.storycreate.Editor : 4]]
```

now if I combine this to get a list of stories where joe is either the owner or an editor:

```
def hql = "from Story as s left outer join s.editors as se where (s.owner.username='joe' OR se.user.username='joe')"
def results = Story.executeQuery(hql)
```

I get the incorrect results (missing Story 2 where joe is owner)

```
Result: [[com.storycreate.Story : 3, com.storycreate.Editor : 1], [com.storycreate.Story : 4, com.storycreate.Editor : 4]]
```

Eventually, I want the query to give me a list of all stories where isPublic is true OR logged in user is the owner, editor, or viewer of the story.  But I seem to be missing some understanding of how Hibernate is working here.

Comment: If joe is the owner of story 2 and 3, I think this result `Result: [[com.storycreate.Story : 3, com.storycreate.Editor : 1], [com.storycreate.Story : 2, null]]` is not showing it.

Comment: Maybe I'm I not understanding the results.  I'm a bit of a newbie with Grails.  To me the result shows 2 rows.  The first showing a Story object of ID 3 and the second show a Story object ID 2.  Is that not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integration spec passes for me in 2.4.3:

```
class StoryControllerIntSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def setup() {
        User joe = new User(userName: "joe").save()
        User bar = new User(userName: "bar").save()
        User foo = new User(userName: "foo").save()

        // joe as both owner and editor
        Story s1 = new Story(isPublic: true, title: "Story1", owner: joe)
        Editor e1 = new Editor(user: joe)
        s1.addToEditors(e1)

        // joe only as owner
        Story s2 = new Story(isPublic: true, title: "Story2", owner: joe)
        Editor e2 = new Editor(user: foo)
        s2.addToEditors(e2)

        // joe only as editor
        Story s3 = new Story(isPublic: true, title: "Story3", owner: bar)
        Editor e3 = new Editor(user: joe)
        s3.addToEditors(e3)

        // joe not related to story
        Story s4 = new Story(isPublic: true, title: "Story4", owner: foo)
        Editor e4 = new Editor(user: bar)
        s4.addToEditors(e4)

        [s1, s2, s3, s4]*.save()
    }

    void "test something"() {
        given:
        StoryController controller = new StoryController()

        when:
        def model = controller.index()

        then:
        model.result.size() == 3
        def stories = model.result.collect { it[0] }
        stories.size() == 3
        stories*.title == ['Story1', 'Story2', 'Story3']
    }
}

// Controller
class StoryController {

    def index() {
        def hql = "from Story as s left outer join s.editors as se \
                   where (s.owner.userName='joe' OR se.user.userName='joe')"
        def results = Story.executeQuery(hql)

        [result: results]
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, dmahapatro.  Thank you for trying that out and maybe confirming I'm doing this correctly.  Could be an issue with my version of Grails and Hibernate (currently: 4.3.5.4).  I'll create an updated environment to test this out. I would think it wouldn't matter, but what datasource are you using?  H2 in memory or a SQL database?

Comment: Upgraded to Grails 2.4.3 and my Hibernate plugin from 4.3.5.4 to 4.3.6.1 and the query worked.  For some reason the upgrade caused all my autoTimestamp fields (dateCreated and lastUpdated) to stop working.  I had to comment them out...but that's for another time.  Thanks for helping me out!  I marked it as the answer but my 0 reputation doesn't allow me to plus 1 it.

Comment: It's ok. Glad that was helpful. :) @jer0dh

Comment: Discovered that the default hibernate plugin version for Grails 2.4.3 is 4.3.5.5.  I downgraded to this version and now the autotimestamp works.